# Windows get short path to a file before creating it

Tags: powershell, window, cmd

I'm trying to get a short path of a file before the file is created. I found an example which can convert a path to a shortPath if the folder or file existed. However, is there a way to get short path before the file even exist?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is impossible.

Comment: I agree with dbenham.  Maybe you could update your question with the root problem and we could work to help you with some other solution.

Comment: the algorithm that creates shorts names does not look so hard to be recreated in powershell: 1.max lenght of file name is 12 symbold and 8 for dirs and files without extension . 2. only 3 letters are allowed for file extension.  3. last 2 symbols are taken for ~N where N is the number 4. if the N must have more than one digit text become shorter with 1 letter.

Comment: @npocmaka I like your suggestion of an algorithm, but it doesn't take into account the current state of the file system. Eg the short form of a proposed c:\one\verydanglongfoo.txt depends on whether c:\one\verydanglongbar.txt exists or not.

Comment: Yes.You'll need to keep a list of files with short names and to check if file with the short name exist .If you already have verydanglongbar.txt the short name of verydanglongfoo.txt will be  VERYDA~2.TXT.It's just incrementing ~N .But if both files does not exist we'll have a problem.

Comment: If both files don't exist you could just start with `N == 1` surely? But anyway, a worse problem is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename (See Overview point 4.) There are some cases where there is an undocumented hash used. Oh well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments. I think the easiest way to solve this problem is:

```
if file DOES NOT existed:
  generate shortPath
  return shortPath
else:
  touch a new file with exact name expected.
  generate shortPath
  remove temp file
  return shortPath
```